# Cannot get isotope to sort by number

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to get isotope to sort by the number in p.number (one p.number is inside each div.box) and all of the div.box are inside #content (my jquery is below to build this markup)   But right now all of the div.box divs are just stacking on top of each other --- What I want is when when I click on the button, the div.box will sort by the number which is found in the p.number tag

This is the error I get in the web console: TypeError: '.number parseInt' is not a function (evaluating 'ea')

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="sorts">
            <button>sort by number</button>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div> 
    </div>

    <script>        

        var myData = [
    {
        "number" : "15", 
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 1"
    },
    {
        "number" : "28",
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 2"
    },
    {
        "number" : "58",
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 3"
    },
    {
        "number" : "37",
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 4"
    },
    {
        "number" : "4",
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 5"
    },
    {
        "number" : "8",
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 6"
    },
    {
        "number" : "23", 
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 7"
    },
    {
        "number" : "88",
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 8"
    },
    {
        "number" : "27",
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 9"
    },
    {
        "number" : "67",
        "promoimage_title" : "Title here item 10"
    }

];


        $.each(myData, function(index, value) {
                $('#content').append("<div class='box'><p class='number'>"+value.number+"</p><p class='box-title'>"+value.promoimage_title+"</p></div>");
        });

        var $container = $('#content');                 

          $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.box',
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            getSortData: {
              number: '.number parseInt'
            }
          });



        $('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
            $container.isotope({ sortBy: 'number' });
        });


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Works for me [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/px84g3x0/). How are you loading your js? jQuery 1st?

Comment: Yeah, i have jquery first, but should it be that way?  does it have to be a certain type of jquery